# Conditional sum metric (sub-total column) in Kibana data table

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I need to display subtotal columns in a Kibana data table. Not filtering the entire table, but only certain columns.

I've seen [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54125218/12400783) about doing conditional counts in a metric's JSON input field:

```
{
  "script":{
    "inline": "doc['SomeField'].value == 'SomeValue' ?  1 : 0", 
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

But no reference to conditional sums of numeric data. My loosely expressed need:

```
sum(btyes) where category = [write]
```

Alternatively, the [Kibana Enhanced Table plugin](https://github.com/fbaligand/kibana-enhanced-table) was [suggested](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3620#issuecomment-390975104) as a way to implement computed columns.

Is it possible to achieve conditional sums using JSON input on a specific data table metric? Is anyone using the plugin? Should it be done upstream in an elasticsearch index? What is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is a simple change to show the actual value in the true condition, rather than a 1 for counting :

```
{
  "script" : "doc['category.keyword'].value == 'write' ? doc['bytes'].value : 0"
}
```